# Need to pass Request object to method

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, parameters

I'm writing a C# class in an ASP.Net 4.6.1 web application. I want to pass the Request object to a method in this class. I put a using statement for System.Web and I'm able to reference the HttpContext class. In the body of the class I can reference HttpContext.Current.Request, but when I try to do this in the method parameters, it recognizes HttpContext, but it has no properties or methods. Is it possible to pass the Request object as a parameter to a method in a class?

Comment: Please post the code you are trying so we can tell you what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Request` is not a valid method parameter definition because it isn't a qualified typename, it is a property accessor. The type of `HttpContext.Current.Request` is `System.Web.HttpRequest` and the method parameter can be named with or without the namespace.

`MyMethod(HttpRequest request) {}` is right,
`MyMethod(HttpContext.Current.Request request) {}` isn't

Comment: Beautiful. Works perfectly. Thanks so much for the fix and the explanation.